# How to find number from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
String str = "USD  SBFARE 4067.71 OVDPCT 8P SBMARKUP 0A  TPS 59486 CC 0P  OTH 0A"
```

I need `"8" (OVDPCT 8P)` from this string.

Number always follow OVDPCT and precede with a P.

This 8 may be 10,12 etc means any number.

How can i by using c#.?

Comment: What's the pattern? Does the number always follow `OVDPCT` and precede a `P`? Or is it always the 5th string? Also, what solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: @mart1n  yes always follow OVDPCT and precede with p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many different variants are we talking about?

If it's always `OVDPCT *P` then the pattern can be:

```
.*OVDPCT (\d+)P.*
```

You can use it like this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str,@".*OVDPCT (\d+)P.*");
int num = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Note: I'm being very rough here, you'd probably want to check `match.Success` and also use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: I think that the reason why the OP is asking this question is because there is a small bug in your code: group instead of groups

Answer (score 2):

So you can use a regular expression to do that

```
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, "OVDPCT (?<Number>\\d+)P", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if(match.Success)
{
    var number = match.Groups["Number"].Value;
}
```

But this line seems like an data base record isn't it?

Comment: Your pattern seems to need a heading "@".

Comment: or "\\" if you prefer :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work then:

```
.*?OVDPCT (\d+)P.*
```

Answer (score 0):

\d+ is the regex for an integer number. So

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

will give you that number as a string. Int32.Parse(resultString) will then give you the number.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the scrappy code but something like this:

```
var str = "USD  SBFARE 4067.71 OVDPCT 8P SBMARKUP 0A  TPS 59486 CC 0P  OTH 0A";

var strAsArray = str.Split(" ".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var subject = strAsArray[4].Trim(); // assuming fifth element

var value = new Regex("^[0-9]+").Match(subject).Value;

Console.WriteLine("Found: ", value);
```

Comment: Why not just use a regex on the whole thing rather than just the final part to check for a number? Seems a little inefficient.

Comment: Because there are other numbers that were not of interest in the OP - at least that's how I read it

Comment: ...although I've now seen the amended OP and I agree that this is not efficient given that the input string is more consistent than originally described!